# How to pass multiple argument and return multiple argument in function

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function that take two argument and return two arguments I want to pass and return two arguments

I tried this but doesn't work I get error
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

```
df['col1'], df['col2'] = zip(*df.apply(lambda x: myfunc(df['description'], df['title']), axis=1))
```

Comment: What's the type of input and output arguments. Are they a String?

Comment: the output are   word_tokenize & sent_tokenize and the inputs are String

Answer (score 1):

Trying to write a small example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Description":["A", "B"], "Title":["Hello1", "Hello2"]})

def myfunc(x,y): return x+y, y+x

df['col2'] = df.apply(lambda x: myfunc(x['Description'], x['Title']), axis=1)

df
```

**OUTPUT**

```
 Description   Title                col2
0           A  Hello1  (AHello1, Hello1A)
1           B  Hello2  (BHello2, Hello2B)
```

When you use `.apply(func, axis=1)`, the function is applied *line by line*, and each line is the `x`. In other words, when you process the first line, `x["Description"]` is "A" and `x["Title"]` is "Hello2". As you can see, the lambda function written in your code does not use the `x` at any point, but it refers to the global `df`.

**FOLLOW UP**: to answer your question if we can have 2 columns:

```
df[["col1"]], df[["col2"]] = zip(*(df.apply(lambda x: myfunc(x['Description'], x['Title']), axis=1)))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
 Description   Title     col1     col2
0           A  Hello1  AHello1  Hello1A
1           B  Hello2  BHello2  Hello2B
```

Comment: is it not possible to have two columns ?